# Bitbucket pull-request: require green builds from different repository

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, bamboo

We're using Bitbucket with Bamboo and we need to require that we have green builds both in the repository that the pull-request is submitted to but also a green build from Bamboo related to a different repository that depends on the target repo.  Right now it seems to exclude any builds that weren't using the repository in question even if the branch name was the same.  Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't know of any easy way to report to a separate repo.

If you have access to the commit of the main repository in the target repo's build, you could use [the Bitbucket API](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/how-tos/updating-build-status-for-commits/) to report the status back to the pull request.

The repos won't have any connection based on branch name unfortunately. You could probably checkout the first repo at that branch and lookup the HEAD commit.

Overall, the workflow in the target repo would be

1. Do the build on the target repo
2. As a build step, checkout the main repo, switch to the branch, get the commit and write to a file
3. Read the commit from file into a variable using the [Inject Variable task](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/configuring-a-variables-task-687213475.html) so it is available as a variable later on.
4. In the last normal build step, create a temp file (e.g. `.success`)
5. An a Final Step (which runs regardless of pass/fail) check for that temp file. If it is there, the build passed. Make a JSON request to the BitBucket API endpoint to the main repo for the commit you looked up before, reporting pass/fail.